# Proof for Moore-Penrose inverse of transposed matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, pseudoinverse

I would like to ask how to prove that Moore-Penrose inverse of $A^T$ is $(A^+)^T$. I know that I can do it by proving all 4 properties but I am stuck at proving that 
$(A^+A)^T=A^+A$ and $(AA^+)^T=AA^+$

Comment: Please explain notations and give references...

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you mean? What is unclear in my question? @dan_fulea the 4 properties that must be satisfied in order that matrix is Moore-Penrose inverse are: 1) $AA^+A=A$ 2) $A^+AA^+=A^+$ 3) $(A^+A)^T=A^+A$ and 4) $(AA^+)^T=AA^+$. I managed to prove 1) and 2) I don't know how to prove 3) and 4). notation : $A^+$ is More-Penrose inverse and $A^T$ means transposed matrix.

Comment: Well, questions should somehow make clear the details and the notations, in our case: What is $A^+$? Is it the Moore-Penrose inverse of $A$? A reference to the Moore-Penrose inverse, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse, uniqueness, properties would give a better context to the question. "All 4 properies" would be immediately clear, if they are listed. Also we have to guess in which context we need to show $(A^+A)^T=A^+A$, for which property, starting from which properties...

Comment: So we are working over $\Bbb R$?

Answer (score 1):

We work over $\Bbb R$. So the transpose and the hermitean conjugation coincide.

We start with $A^+$ satisfying the defining properties of a pseudoinverse:

- $(1)$ $AA^+A = A$,
- $(2)$ $A^+AA^+ = A^+$,
- $(3)$ $(A^+A)^T = A^+A$, i.e. $(3')$ $A^T(A^+)^T=A^+A$,
- $(4)$ $(AA^+)^T = AA^+$, i.e. $(4')$ $(A^+)^TA^T=AA^+$.

Let $B=A^T$. We denote by $X$ the matrix $(A^+)^T$,
$$X=(A^+)^T\ .$$
We apply the transposition in the above relations $(1)$, $(2)$, 
and use $(3')$, $(4')$ in terms of the new notations.

- $(1)^T$ $BXB = B$,
- $(2)^T$ $XBX = X$,
- $(3')$ $BX=X^TB^T$,
- $(4')$ $XB=B^TX^T$.

Above, we can rewrite $X^TB^T=(BX)^T$, $B^TX^T=(XB)^T$.

By definition $X$ is $B^+$.

This is explicitly $(A^+)^T=(A^T)^+$.

$\square$

*Note:* I hope this also explains my comment.

Answer (score 1):

> I am stuck at proving that $(A^+A)^T=A^+A$ and $(AA^+)^T=AA^+$.

You cannot prove that because it isn't true in general (unless $A$ is real).

What you should prove is that both $A^T(A^+)^T$ and $(A^+)^TA^T$ are Hermitian, but this is obviously true because they are the transposes of $A^+A$ and $AA^+$, and the latter two products are Hermitian by the definition of $A^+$.